# Ibeacon coding opening and closing

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I am working on android project related to beacon.

I have a question...if we want to receive message than our bluetooth device should be on always..

> Qus->
> can their is any way that our app is closed and bluetooth is also closed
>
> and when our device comes under range of beacon the bluetooth should be on automatically .

Comment: beacon technology is required the bluetooth connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

No. Beacons are Bluetooth Low Energy devices. As the name says, beacons can function only if your device Bluetooth is turned on. Then only the device will detect beacons.

Comment: suppose we are near the mall having beacon inside...and how we get to know that their is beacon ...if we forgot to open the bluetooth..because its common behaviour of people that their bluetooth device is off

Comment: You cannot. If you want your device to detect beacons and push you notifications, then your bluetooth should be turned on. End of the story

Comment: their should be a technique that if you come under range then bluetooth and app should be open...or another possibilty is we should get a notification related to that...and when we click on the notification our bluetooth device should open....is that possible?????

Comment: You have to write logic for using the device location or something. If your device is within your location coordinate, then prompt the user to turn on bluetooth to receive beacon notifications.There is no other option to get beacon notification rather than switching on bluetooth.

Comment: ok thanks...i want to ask one more thing...please tell me that.does ibeacon work on android device..or eddy-stone work on android..i have estimode beacon ..but i dont know it is eddystone or ibeacon supportable....please clear the difference between ibeacon,eddystone,estimode..i am confused

Comment: i downloaded ibeacon demo from internet and it is scanning all the beacons..but does not give uuid of estimide beacons

Comment: First of all it's not estimide. It's Estimote. Android devices supports both iBeacons and normal beacons.

Comment: Please google and see before posting such broad questions.You'll get all details in google

Comment: I searched over google  and i am confused between estimote eddistone and estimote ibeacons...which is for android device

Comment: google says ibeacon is for ios and eddystone is for android..but ibeacon  also works with android..thats why i am confused.

Comment: Did you read the documentation in Estimote website? It clearly says "While iBeacon is officially supported by iOS devices only, Eddystone has official support for both iOS and Android." Refer http://developer.estimote.com/eddystone/

Comment: i know ...but then how ibeacon support android...thats my question

Comment: and i searched all documentations.

Comment: What are you actually asking??

Comment: i am asking that i downloaded an android ibeacon sdk demo project and it is scanning all the ibeacons on android...but i read on google that ibeacon works with ios and if we want to use beacons onandroid that we use eddistone rather than ibeacon...so i am confused how that ibeacon demo working on android.....check out that link---   https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Comment: Android devices can detect both Eddystone beacons and iBeacons. But iOS can detect only iBeacons. End of the story

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104622/discussion-between-jitender-and-jas).